# Organizing results by category explanation

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Can someone please explain what is going on in the code below? I understand it until the `$categories[$category][] = $row['agency'];` line.

```
$categories = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $category = $row['category'];
    $categories[$category][] = $row['agency'];
}
```

Comment: after the while add print_r($categories) that will show you whats going on

Comment: Thanks, but I am still confused as to how this line `$categories[$category][] = $row['agency'];` works. What exactly is it doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The results you are getting from your database are likely:

**Category           Agency**

```
Security     Police
Security     CIA
Security     FBI
Government   Education
Government   Health
Misc         AnotherAgency
```

The $category = $row['Category'];  gets the value from the result for the Category (i.e Security, Government, Misc).

After that the Categories array is added to.  It is an array of arrays. So it stores for each category an array of agencies.

```
array('Security'   => array('Police', 'CIA', 'FBI'),
      'Government' => array('Education', 'Health'),
      'Misc'       => array('AnotherAgency'));
```

Answer (score 0):

`$row['agency']` is a vector. It is getting "pushed" onto the vector `$categories[$category]'. It is equivalent to the line

```
array_push($categories[$category], $row['agency']);
```